# Why does my ActionFilterAttribute's not execute before a post with ajax requisition?

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-5, action

I have trying use an overriding OnActionExecute on my controller for insert other values in model received from post using jQuery.post, but it happens that on this case the OnActionExecute is not called before my "Save" action. Exist a way that I can chage my received model before the POST action?

This is my OnActionExecuting (example):

```
protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
{
    if (filterContext.ActionParameters.ContainsKey("model") || filterContext.ActionParameters.ContainsKey("Model"))
    {
        var result = filterContext.ActionParameters["model"] as Apoio;
        if (result != null) result.StringProperty = "value of string property";
    }
}
```

It's is necessary for me because my model have relations 1:N (follow):
Action:

```
public ActionResult Save(Model mymodel)
{
    // implementation
}
```

Models:

```
public class Model
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string StringPropert { get; set; }
    private ICollection<ModelChild> _listChild;
    public ICollection<ModelChild> ListChild { 
        get
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(StringProperties))
                {
                    var modelChild = new ModelChild(StringProperty);
        var list = (from item in model.GetAllChilds(StringProperty).Where(item => item .MasterId == this.Id) select item).ToList();
                    return list;
                }
                return _listChild;
            } 
    }
}


public class ModelChild
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string StringPropert { get; set; }
    public int MasterId { get; set; } // <== reference to Model.Id
}
```

Anybody have a idea?
Thanks